# C++ Builder XE5 , how to show selected text in richedit

Tags: c++builder, richedit, trichedit

I want to know the method or the code that I can use to have the selected text from the RichEdit in VCL on C++Builder XE5.

I can change the color of selected text with this code :

```
re->SelAttributes->Color = TheColorWanted;
```

But I don't know how can I proceed to show for example the selected text in the RichEdit.

Comment: It is not clear whether you want to GET the selected text, OVERWRITE text that is already selected, or HIGHLIGHT new text to make it selected.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the RichEdit's `SelStart`, `SelLength` and `SelText` properties.